# Limit of difference of exponentials equal to $L$ implies another limit is the same

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (e^{a_{n+1}} - e^{a_n}) = L $. Prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{a_n}}{n} = L$$

I tried to manipulate the second limit into:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{a_{n+1}}}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{a_{n+1}} - e^{a_n} + e^{a_n}}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{a_{n}}}{n} $$

but this is only true if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{a_{n}}}{n}$ exists, which we don't know to be the case. What other tricks could I try? I'm not seeing a way out of this one.

Comment: @JustANoob I don't quite get what you mean. Could you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: The exponentials seem to be a red herring: setting $b_n=e^{a_n}$ gives a more standard problem, which can be verified with an epsilon-delta proof.

Comment: @GregMartin how? I tried transforming $b_n$ into a telescopic sum involving the terms $b_k - b_{k-1}$ but it didn't lead anywhere

Comment: Nevermind, it seems the telescoping idea works. I'll put it here later.

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of Stolz-Cesaro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there is $N\in\mathbb N>0$ such that
$$ L-\varepsilon<e^{a_{n+1}} - e^{a_n}<L+\varepsilon $$
for $n\ge N$. Letting $n>N+1$ and $k=N,N+1,\cdots,n-1$, one has
$$ \sum_{k=N}^{n-1}(L-\varepsilon)<\sum_{k=N}^{n-1}(e^{a_{k+1}} - e^{a_k})<\sum_{k=N}^{n-1}(L+\varepsilon )$$
or
$$ (n-N)(L-\varepsilon)<e^{a_{n}} - e^{a_N}<(n-N)(L+\varepsilon). $$
This gives
$$ L-\varepsilon<\frac{e^{a_{n}} - e^{a_N}}{n-N}<L+\varepsilon $$
which implies
$$  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{a_{n}}}{n}=L. $$